# Session array only stores the last element

Tags: php

I am trying to track the pages a user visits and the day of the visits using session variables.  In my pages, I assigned the variables as arrays like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page']=array();
$_SESSION['page'][]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SESSION['time']=array();
$_SESSION['time'][]=date("m/d/y", time());
```

I used the following script to print the variables out:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['page']);
print_r($_SESSION['time']);
?>
```

After I visited several pages, the above script only printed the last page I visited instead of showing all the pages.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot please?  Thank you.

Comment: you could just let google analytics do it for you

Comment: `$_SESSION['page']=array();`  Every time you load a page, you are replacing `'page'` with a blank array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you initialize the arrays again and again on every page visit. Use something like this instead:

```
// initialize array only if it not already exists:
if(!is_array($_SESSION['page'])) {
    $_SESSION['page']=array();
}
$_SESSION['page'][]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You redeclare array each time, thus cleaning it:

`$_SESSION['page']=array();`

Solution: Check if array exists, add an element.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['page'])){
  $_SESSION['page'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['page'][] = "New data" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you must do it this way:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) {
   $_SESSION['time'] = array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['page'])) {
   $_SESSION['page'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['time'][] = date("m/d/y", time());
```

otherwise, you just overwrite again and again the `'time'` key..

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines from your code.

```
$_SESSION['page']=array();
$_SESSION['time']=array();
```

Above lines are resetting your session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-setting them to empty array each time you save new session:

```
$_SESSION['page']=array(); // the $_SESSION['page'] now is empty
$_SESSION['page'][]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store that kind of information in a DB and call it whenever you need it.

But to answer your exact question about doing it in the session variable, just use something like the following:

```
session_start();

/****Record visit****/
$newvisit=array();
$newvisit['page']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$newvisit['time']=date("m/d/y",time());

/****Store visit in SESSION****/
if(!empty($_SESSION['visits'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['visits'],$newvisit);
}else{
    $_SESSION['visits'][0]=$newvisit;
}
```

Like others have mentioned, the main problem with your code is that you were writing over the same session variable.